# Did Daniel Ekechukwu resurrect from the dead?

Tags: medical-science, history, mortality

According to [this four-part report](http://www.heavensfamily.org/ss/resurrection-from-the-dead-pastor-daniel-ekechukwu), a man named Daniel Ekechukwu, a resident of Nigera, died November 30, 2001 and came back to life December 2, 2001. A literal and modern resurrection. The same story can be found on a number of other websites, but the one I linked seems to be the original posting. This claim seems to be relatively well substantiated in comparison to most other stories of miraculous healings, given eyewitness reports from the man himself, the mortician, and from people who were present when Daniel came back to life as well as a photo of the death certificate Thus, at the very least, on the surface this appears to be an entirely legitimate resurrection event.

How credible is the evidence behind this story?

Comment: According to that report, the sources are:  (1) Pastor Daniel Ekechukwu; (2) Pastor Daniel Ekechukwu's booklet; (3) Pastor Daniel Ekechukwu's sermon; (4) A "documentary" produced by an evangelical church; (5) a close friend of Pastor Daniel Ekechukwu; (6) Pastor Daniel Ekechukwu’s Public Relations Director. Is that "well substantiated"?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: Edited to point out that its more substantial than most such claims.

Comment: So if I was to declare (and make that declaration in multiple places) that I had risen from the dead, it must be true? I'll bet I could get my best friend to agree with that too. Why is this credible evidence for the event? Does saying so three times make it so?

Comment: I am wracking my brain for the name of the book I read decades ago. Romeo Effect? Romeo Error? Romeo Syndrome? Google is failing me. It described how common it was, especially outside of a modern hospital, to be mistakenly declared dead. It provides a prosaic alternative to this supernatural explanation.

Comment: Were I grew up there is a person with the nickname of "O morto", meaning"The dead". In the 1950's a boy was declared dead, my mother (in her youth) was one of the persons that attended the first day of the wake, on the next day (funeral day) the boy woke, stand up, turned to his mother and asked "why are all this people here?" it was alive and it lived on to the new millenium. It wasn't declared neither a saint nor it was declared a miracle (as a father I do believe his fathers may have felt like indeed it was). Several eyewitness were present, but was told as wrong death diagnosis.

Comment: @Oddthinking-Is the syndrome your describing called as Lazarus phenomenon? If so, that is discussed here-http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2121643/.

Comment: @Odd The definition of death tends to change with technology and the instrumentation available.

Comment: @Oddthinking Yep, for these reasons (among others) some professions like EMTs are strictly prohibited from declaring death on the scene except in extremely obvious situations.